# Como validar um esquema Yup aninhado e condicionalmente opcional

Tags: javascript, node.js, validação, schema, yup

Estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar validar um esquema aninhado com Yup ().

Meu cenário é que eu tenho a seguinte payload (que nem sempre pode conter maxAge e maxAge, mas pelo menos um deles):

```
{
  name: 'userName',
  calc: [{
    maxAge:{
      day:'0',
      month:'0',
      year:'5',
    },
    minAge:{
      day:'12',
      month:'12',
      year:'4',
    }
  }],
}
```

O problema é que maxAge e minAge são "opcionais", mas é necessário pelo menos um, de modo que o conteúdo interno (dia, mês, ano) seja opcional, mas se um maxAge ou minAge for passado, pelo menos um dos conteúdo interno é obrigatorio.

Eu tentei o seguinte código:

```
const Yup = require('yup');

(async () => {
  try {
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      name: Yup.string()
        .required()
        .trim()
        .min(2, `Name must have at least 3 characters`)
        .max(50, `Name must have at maximum 50 characters`)
        .matches(/^[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ\- &]*$/, 'Name is not valid')
        .required(),
      calc: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object()
        .shape(
          { 
            maxAge: Yup.object()
            .shape({
              year: Yup.string().optional(),
              month: Yup.string().optional(),
              days: Yup.string().optional()
            }).when('minAge', {
              is: '' || undefined || {} || null,
              then: Yup.object().shape({
                year: Yup.string(),
                month: Yup.string(),
                days: Yup.string()
              }).required('This minAge is required.'),
              otherwise: Yup.object()
            }), 

            minAge: Yup.object()
            .shape({
              year: Yup.string().optional(),
              month: Yup.string().optional(),
              days: Yup.string().optional()
            }).when('maxAge', {
              is: '' || undefined || {} || null,
              then: Yup.object().shape({
                year: Yup.string(),
                month: Yup.string(),
                days: Yup.string()
              }).required('This minAge is required.'),
              otherwise: Yup.object()
            }),

          },
          [['minAge', 'maxAge']]
        )
        .required(),
      )
    });

    let test = await schema.validate(
      {
        name: 'Jonas',
        calc: [{

        }],
      },
      { abortEarly: false }
    );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Tem como fazer a sua própria validação. No caso você colocaria a função de validação no `calc` e faz o que quiser na função, como nesse [exemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pwv8yl41lq). Já tentou algo do tipo?